# How to write UDAF for hive using java that accept multiple columns as arguments?

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I want to calculate currency_rate based on few inputs like date, var_currecy_code, 
 fxd_crncy_code.

We have all data in our hive table now we need to calculate currency_rate based on the maximum date and some more inputs as mentioned above by using hive UDAF.

Comment: We're going to need some more info, your question is a bit vague

Answer (score 1):

Hive UDF can accept a Tuple as a parameter.

Within the function, you check the length of the tuple, and extract the necessary order for your logic